# How to combine 2 arrays, with which have same value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arraylist

I have arrays

```
 var array1 = [
    {"id" : 1,"val1" : 1,"val2": 1},
    {"id" : 2,"val1" : 2,"val2": 1},
    {"id" : 3,"val1" : 0,"val2": 0}
 ];

 var array2 = [
    {"id" : 1,"val1" : 1,"val3": 1},
    {"id" : 2,"val3": 1},
    {"id" : 3,"val3": 0}
 ];
```

I want the output to be like this

```
 var array3 = [
   {"id" : 1,"val1" : 1,"val2": 1, "val3" : 1},
   {"id" : 2,"val1" : 2, "val3" : 1},
   {"id" : 3,"val1" : 0, "val3" : 0}
 ];
```

Is there a simple(r) shortcut? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
var array3 = array1.map(function(o, i) {
               return Object.assign({}, array2[i], o)
             })
```